# How to make page responsive to any resolution?

Tags: jquery, html, css, grid, media-queries

I am a new to web designing,so please help me.I am trying to display a search box on a web page.At 100% resolution it looks fine.But when I increase the resolution of the screen it changes its original place and containts gets distracted.
Here is the normal image of my search box:
[image]

and this is after i zoom the screen by ctrl+ + :
[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9yZr.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrexC.png`enter code here`

this is a code of my search box:

```
    <!--start SearchBox section-->
    <center>
        <section id="searchbox"style="background:white">
            <div class="container" style="margin-top:0px;">
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">

               <form >
                    <center>
                            <div id="SearchBoxBorder" style="background:white;border:none;border-radius:5px;margin-top:20px;width:800px;">
                            <table id="mytable" >
                                    <td style="width:300px;background:white;">
                                       <center> <div class="form-group">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchtopicTxt" placeholder="I am looking for">
                                        </div></center>
                                     </td>

                                     <td style="width:50px ;text-align:right;background:white;"> <center><strong> in</strong></center>    </td>

                                     <td style="width:400px;background:white;">
                                     <center>
                                             <div class="input-group" style="position: relative;">
                                                   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="this locality" id="searchLocalityTxt">
                                                   <div class="input-group-btn">
                                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"  data-toggle="dropdown" 
                                                            id="dropdownBtn">Select<span class="caret"></span></button>



                                                             <!--City dropdown -->
                                                                    <div class="SearchCities" id="dialog" title="Basic dialog" >

                                                                            <div id="outer_div" style="">



                                                                                        <div id="innerLeft_div" style="">
                                                                                            <h5 id="impcities_h5" >Important Cities:</h5>
                                                                                            <div id="ill_div" >
                                                                                            <ul class="city" id="left1_ul" type="none";>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Delhi</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Agra</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Shrinagar</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Noida</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Himachal</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Patna</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Chandigarth</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Shimla</a></li>
                                                                                            </ul>
                                                                                            </div>

                                                                                            <div id="ilr_div" >
                                                                                            <ul class="city" id="left2_ul" type="none";>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Jaipur</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Uti</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Punjab</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Kashi</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Ayodhya</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Sikkim</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Jabalpur</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Banaras</a></li>


                                                                                            </ul>
                                                                                            </div>

                                                                                        </div><!--/innerLeft-->

                                                                                        <div id="innerRight_div" style="">
                                                                                            <a class="close" id="cross">&times;</a>
                                                                                            <h5  id="ss" style="margin-top:10px;">All Cities :</h5>
                                                                                            <!--Page1------------------------------------------------------------------->
                                                                                            <div n class="page1" id="irl_div" >
                                                                                            <ul class="city" id="left1_ul" type="none";>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Delhi</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Agra</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Shrinagar</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Noida</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Himachal</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Patna</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Chandigarth</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Shimla</a></li>
                                                                                            </ul>
                                                                                            </div>
                                                                                            <div class="page1" id="irm_div" >
                                                                                            <ul class="city" id="left1_ul" type="none";>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Delhi</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Agra</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Shrinagar</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Noida</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Himachal</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Patna</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Chandigarth</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Shimla</a></li>
                                                                                            </ul>
                                                                                            </div>
                                                                                            <div class="page1" id="irr_div" >
                                                                                            <ul class="city" id="left1_ul" type="none";>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Delhi</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Agra</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Shrinagar</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Noida</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Himachal</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Patna</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Chandigarth</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a>Shimla</a></li>
                                                                                            </ul>
                                                                                            </div>

                                                                                            <div class="clear">
                                                                                                <div class="right nextPre" id="jqPagination">

                                                                                                    <span style="width:100px"><a id="prevMetroCities" title="Previous" class="prev">Previous</a></span>
                                                                                                    <span style="width:100px"><a id="nextMetroCities"  title="Next" class="next">Next</a></span>

                                                                                                </div>
                                                                                            </div>


                                                                                        </div><!--/innerRight-->
                                                                            </div><!--/outer-->
                                                                        </div><!--/SearchCities dropdown-->


                                                             </div><!-- /btn-group -->
                                                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="searchBtn" ><i class="icon-search" style="font-size:20px"></i>  Search</button>
                                             </div><!-- /input-group -->
                                           </center>         
                                     </td>

                            </table>
                        </center>
                    </form>

    </div><!--/col-lg-12-->
</div><!--/row-->
    </div><!--/end of container-->
</section>
</center>
<!--End of SearchBox section-->
```

And css for above search box:

```
    table#mytable
    {
    width:100%;

    }
strong { font-size:28px; margin:0px 20px 0 0px; height:30px; line-height:30px; color:#333333; }

.SearchCities {

      position:absolute;
      margin-top:1px;
      top: 100%;
      right:134px;
      z-index:1;


    }

#dropdownBtn{
     background:white;border-top-width:5px;border-right-width:5px;border-bottom-width:5px;border-left-width:1px;border-color:#eee;height:42px;border-radius:0px;text-align:center;color:black; margin-right:20px;margin-top:2px;
}

#dropdownBtn:focus, #dropdownBtn:active {
    outline: none;
}

#searchtopicTxt{
border-width:5px;background:white; margin-top:17px; margin-left:15px; margin-right:10px;width:300px;border-style:solid;border-width:5px;border-color:#eee;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;height:42px; font-size:18px;
}

#searchLocalityTxt{
   border-width:5px;background:white; margin-top:2px; margin-left:10px; margin- right:20px;width:;font-size:18px;
border-style:solid;border-width:5px;border-color:#eee;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;height:42px;position:relative;
}

#searchBtn{
       margin-right:20px;border-radius:0px;
}
```

Also if i open same page in 1.mozila and 2.chrome output is different for both.But i dont want that i want it to make responsive to any resolution.
It would be very helpful if any one suggest me a solution on this problem.
So,please Help me.
Thank u in advence.

Comment: `<center>` elements were deprecated a long time ago.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options for the responsive layout

```
1. Defining all the heights and widths in %
2. You can use the media queries
```

[Media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media0)

Here is a good link to start with [Responsive-web-design](http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design)

Comment: [Agreed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19396219/how-to-make-page-responsive-to-any-resolution/19396230#19396230)

Answer (score 1):

***Adjust the css***

1. All the heights and widths are givern in  max-width.
2. And allso given in % not in px.

****Example****

```
.SearchCities
{
    max-width:20%;
    max-height:10%;
}
```

1. Other way you can use new theme, wordpress 2013 is responsive link
   [enter link description here][1]

   http://wordpress.org/

Answer (score 0):

Use **CSS media queries.**

Here is the [Link](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) that will help you understand all the things about it.

You can also read the below for further clarity.

> http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media0

Hope this helps.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: Nope. It should be an answer, as I am not suggesting something or asking a question. I am providing an answer as to what to use or what not to use with a w3.org doc for further clarity. - @ahren